# Displaying Textbox Value

Tags: javascript, html

How can I only show the value of a text field, and not the actual white box. So what I have is a simple text field of type number.

```
<input type="number" id="text" value="0"/>
```

What I want to do is only show the value, not the actual box itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with CSS. Just style the box to look like the background of your webpage, and then set the properties of the input box to be disabled so that the user cannot change the values. Finally, you can set the CSS for the cursor so that upon mouseover it doesn't appear like it's a textfield.

Comment: I am using ajax to change the value of the input field. If it is disabled can I still change the value?

Comment: Yes, it is only disabled to the user not to Javascript or what have you.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the borders and set the background-color to transparent with CSS:

```
input
{
    border: none;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code like this:

```
<input type="number" id="text" value="0" style="border:0px;"/>
```

This should produce your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

As heavysixer mentioned, you can use CSS:

```
#text{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: default;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

You'll want to make the font match the rest of your document.  Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/mestekweb/URkca/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="background:#FFFFCC">
<input type="number" id="text" value="0" style="border:0px; background:none;"/>
</div>
```